# Slick 3.2 with Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

The official Slick 3.2 docs
(http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/database.html)
says that Slick can be configured with a normal `javax.sql.DataSource` such as `PGSimpleDataSource` or `PGPoolingDataSource` with this:

```
val db = Database.forDataSource(dataSource: javax.sql.DataSource, Some(size: Int))
```

I can't find a `Database` object to import.

That Database singleton object doesn't even exist in the official ScalaDoc:
http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/api/index.html

I include the following dependencies in my `build.sbt`. Am I missing a slick-postgresql binding or some other dependency that has the missing `Database` object specified in the documentation?

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.0"
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.0.0"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Quick Intro](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/gettingstarted.html#quick-introduction) section says

> ```
> // Use H2Profile to connect to an H2 database
> import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._
> ```
>
> Since we are using H2 as our database system, we need to import features from Slick’s H2Profile. A profile’s api object contains all commonly needed imports from the profile and other parts of Slick such as database handling.

So I believe you want to import the [`PostgresProfile`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/api/index.html#slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile) api:

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
```

Comment: Thank you. FYI, that stuff has been changed in Slick 3.2.0, which is now released.